# How to insert text file to database table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a batchcode.txt which contains list of batch code.

```
645863
302422
430307
821773
599738
671768
732159
```

and so on

I have a table in my database which is called batchcode with fields 'id','batchcode'.

My problem is it wont insert my text file into my table called batchcode. I already did the import and select table but nothing works...

I need some help can anyone help me please.

```
<?php
$host= "localhost";
$user= "root";
$pass= "";
$db="klayton";

$connect= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$connect)die ("Cannot connect!");
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

$file = fopen("batchcode.txt","r");  

while(! feof($file))
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO batchcode( batchcode ) VALUES ('fgets($file)')"; //Insert every read line from txt to mysql database
mysql_query($sql);
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

I got an error that says "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 22"

Comment: How big is `batchcode.txt` in practice (megabytes or terabytes)? Do you have sysadmin access to the (Web & PHP) server?

Comment: Why dont you try mutiple insert in a single query

Comment: The PHP script you've posted here does not contain 22 lines. Anyway, slightly related issue: the `fgets()` function will not be called the way it's currently written. You need to concatenate the value instead, i.e. `$sql = "INSERT INTO batchcode( batchcode ) VALUES ('".fgets($file)."')";` - Note that this is still **vulnerable to SQL injection though**. You should stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and switch to MySQLi / PDO (and start using prepared statements, so you're free from the risk of SQL injections).

Comment: @Nouphal.M: `mysql_query()` can only execute one query at most.

Comment: @Amal Murali What i mentioned was like this `INSERT INTO tableName (fieldname) VALUES ('value1'),('value2')...('valuen');`

Comment: is the id field autoincrement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code the function `fgets($file)` will never be executed, so `! feof($file)` will always `true`, and the while loop keeps running until execution time limitation.

You should rewrite the insert query as following:

```
while( $batchcode = fgets($file) )
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO batchcode( batchcode ) VALUES ('$batchcode')"; 
  mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: not working dude...it stores alot of fgets(Array) not the actual batchcode

Answer (score 1):

When php not in safe mode you can use [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //0 unlimited time, best to use a high number
```

Having one query per line is not a good ideea. Takes a long time as after every insert any indexes are rebuilt. You can use [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) like:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\bigfile.txt' INTO TABLE `database`.`batchcode` LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (`batchcode `);
```

using \r\n or \n depends on your file. The path to the file must be where your mysql client runs.